# Using javascript to dynamically toggle FA icons doesn't return original icon

Tags: javascript, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I have a button which looks like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-xs-block btn-success" :data-lane-id="items[0].lane.id" type="button" v-on:click="callNextCustomer(items[0].lane.id)" :class="hasMorePeople(items)">Next Customer <i class="fas fa-bell"></i></button>
```

When the button has been pressed, `callNextCustomer` function runs the following:

```
const spinnerIcon = '<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
var button = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-lane-id="'+lane_id+'"]')
button[0].disabled = true;
button[0].innerHTML = 'Next Customer ' + spinnerIcon;
// run external request using promise
// when complete run the following
button[0].disabled = false;
button[0].innerHTML = 'Next Customer <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>';
```

When the code is executed, the text changes as expected but the icon doesn't display. Using Google Dev Inspector I can see the icon mark up is present.

[image]

Can anyone explain why this isn't being displayed? I am using Font Awesome v5, <s>I load both the CSS and JS into my page</s>, I load the following JS:

```
<script data-search-pseudo-elements defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please create a runnable snippet that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Btw, I don't know how fontawesome is implemented, but the way I know is for it to use `::before`.  In your DOM screenshot, the `i` tag doesn't  seem to have that.

Comment: Consider switching to fontello.com. You can configure your own iconset for a minimal icon font, and the documentation isn't hidden behind a registration wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you load both icons and put the hidden class on the other one and toggle both icon classes hidden when button is clicked?

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-xs-block btn-success" :data-lane-id="items[0].lane.id" type="button" v-on:click="callNextCustomer(items[0].lane.id)" :class="hasMorePeople(items)">
Next Customer 
<span class="icon hidden spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<i class="icon fas fa-bell"></i>
</button>
```

```
.icon.hidden  {
   display: none;
}
```

When button is clicked you just execute $.jquery command that will toggle the class of .icon as hidden, each click their class will switch hidden.

**1st** click the < span class="icon spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"> hidden class removed

and the < i class="icon `hidden` fas fa-bell"> hidden class added.

**2nd** click vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

**IIRC**, this is because with font awesome 5, all icons are loaded in on page load. Because you are editing the innerHTML after the fact, the "JS" part of the font awesome scripts you added isn't firing again to update with the fa-bell icon.

Comment: What is the recommended way I can re-add the icon to the end of the button?

Comment: honestly, im not too sure as I don't use font awesome 5 like this as I use the react library. Sorry!

Comment: I don't think font awesome requires any Javascript to display icons.

Comment: It depends on the method you use, I think there are multiple available, I remember in the past having to initialise it with some JS before any of the icons loaded up, but the OP may not be using that here.

Comment: I have double-checked, actually I only load the FA js into my page.